# Python pass variable values in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So this is my full code. All I want is append excel files to one excel by sheets from a specific folder. It's GUI and has 3 buttons browse, append, and quit. How do i get path value from browsed folder(filename) ? thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import tkinter as tk
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
root = Tk()

def browsefunc():
    filename = askdirectory()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    return filename


def new_window():
    all_data = pd.DataFrame()
    all_data1 = pd.DataFrame()
    path = browsefunc()+"/*.xlsx"
    for f in glob.glob(path):
        df = pd.read_excel(f,sheetname='Scoring',header=0)
        df1 = pd.read_excel(f,sheetname='Sheet1',header=0)
        all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=False)
        all_data1 = all_data1.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    all_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Scoring')
    all_data1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()

browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc).pack()
Button(root, text='Append', command=new_window).pack()
Button(root, text='quit', command=root.destroy).pack()
pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, so can you edit the question to be more specific?

I think you are trying to get the local variable `filename` (from inside the function `browsefunc`) able to be accessed outside the function as a global variable. Use `return`. [This tutorial](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html) explains it nicely.

At the end of `browsefunc` you add

```
return filename
```

and when you call `browsefunc` you run

```
path = browsefunc()
```

That assigns the variable fdback to whatever you return from browsefunc. It can be an integer, float, string, or list etc.

So, final code is:

```
def browsefunc():
    filename = askdirectory()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    return filename
def new_window():
path = browsefunc()
```

I would recommend using more explicit variable and function names.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: No problem! If it solved your issue, please click on the tick below the upvote/downvote button to mark the question as answered. Also, please read this [tutorial about creating an MSVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting future questions